# MS Office - Hiding ContentControls

Tags: ms-office, office-js

How would you hide a ContentControl when data is filled using a 3. party UI=

Could be (simple example):

_

CC1 - Name: John Doe

CC2 - Phone: 555 1233 4321

CC3 - Title: CTO

_

When using a bookmark to insert Name, Phone and Title it is easy to set the second line to be hidden programaticcaly when using hidden characters.

_

CC1- Name: John Doe

CC3- Title: CTO

__

When using ContentControls this is not possible because ContentControls cannot be hidden using formatting. Grouping the data in one Content Control is not an option as the document management tools that we integrate with does not support this.

How to accomplish the above mentioned example using only ContentControls?

We are looking to use this for an Office.js app as well - using bookmarks is not an option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have a couple of alternatives.

1. Make the content control appearance to be hidden after the insertion. Check out this sample code:

```js
    function insertHideenContentControlInSelection() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var myCC = context.document.getSelection().insertContentControl();
            myCC.appearance = "hidden"; // you can also set it to 'boundingBox' or  'tags'
            return context.sync();
        })
    }
```

2. Not sure if this will work for your scenario but there is a property of content controls that they are removed after editing:

```js
    function insertContentControlWithProperties() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var myCC = context.document.getSelection().insertContentControl();
            myCC.removeWhenEdited = true; 
            return context.sync();
        })


    }
```

Hope this helps.
thanks! Juan.

Comment: Hi!

Thank you for a swift reply. Not sure it will help me - let me try and give a more detailed example to the above.

CC1: Name

CC2: Title

CC3: Phone

Using the code above - will that enable me to not show an empty line if there is no data in CC2? The key thing here is to be able to hide the CC2 incl. the paragraph.

Comment: You can remove the content control, would that help? Not sure why you would like to keep it. Can you elaborate on your scenario? What you are asking is not possible with content controls.

Comment: Removing the content control will not help as I am then unable to update the field if new data from a 3. party software provider needs to be inserted in a document that is already created. So is this a dead end then? Would it be something that would be possible in a future release?

Comment: Yes i think you need to wait until we support bookmarks on the API, its on the pipeline, but not sure exactly when it will land.